# CASE in ORDER BY few columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by, case-when

Using a case-then block, I need to choose how to order my SQL 2008 query, by `[status] ASC, [date] DESC` or just `[date] DESC`.

I know only how to use one column:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @flag = 0
        THEN R.[date] END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @flag = 1
        THEN R.[status] END ASC
```

How to use both columns in second CASE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If your flag is 0, then we'll order
  by (null, r.date desc).
- If not, we'll
  order by (r.Status, r.date desc)

Use the CASE expression to "project" a new value for ordering.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @flag = 0 THEN r.Status ELSE null END,
  r.[date] desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically to put conditional ordering in, you just repeat the CASE statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @flag = 0 THEN R.[date] END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @flag = 0 THEN R.[somethingelse] END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @flag = 1 THEN R.[status] END ASC
;
```

But in your case, the overlap of 'date' means you can simplify it like David B's comment.